# ERROR: could not open file boot.jl

Tags: python, julia

I (want to) use the `pyjulia` package to call Julia from Python. The `pyjulia` tests (python -m unittest discover) all pass when Python calls Julia 0.5.0. When calling Julia 0.6dev however I receive the following error message:

```
JULIA_HOME = /home/opt/inst/julia/0.6/dev/openblas/bin, libjulia_path = /home/opt/inst/julia/0.6/dev/openblas/bin/../lib/libjulia.so.0.6
calling jl_init(b'/home/opt/inst/julia/0.6/dev/openblas/bin')
ERROR: could not open file boot.jl
```

Julia 0.6dev REPL works fine. Anyone some idea? Thanks!